# Why is this not working? [Django]

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I am struggling with this

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}
{% block content %}        
<h1>{{ author.first_name }} {{ author.last_name }}</h1>
{% for book in view.books_by_author %}
    {% if author.last_name  in book.author %}
        <p>{{ book.title }}</p>       
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}    
{% endblock %}
```

"author" is a context variable. This is books_by_author function:

```
def books_by_author(self): 
    books = Book.objects.all()  
    return books
```

This portion is not working:

```
{% if author.last_name  in book.author %}
        <p>{{ book.title }}</p>
```

But when I tried this, it's working. Is there a way to make "book.author" a string or is there a way around?

```
{% if "Twain"  in book.author %}
        <p>{{ book.title }}</p>
```

Comment: @ChristianKönig How can I be more descriptive than this for this particular  problem? I have included [Django] in subject line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should compare with the `last_name` of the *related* author

```
{% if author.last_name in book.author.last_name %}
    <p>{{ book.title }}</p>       
{% endif %}
```

Or more strictly, use `==`:

```
{% if author.last_name == book.author.last_name %}
    <p>{{ book.title }}</p>       
{% endif %}
```